# Last item's value on popup menu not being displayed in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

In the code below, when the user presses a button, the selected value from a popup menu is read and displayed in the command window. The options are "mild", "moderate", and "severe". When I select either of the first two options, I get `selectedSeverity = mild (or moderate)`. However, when I select severe, I get this `selectedSeverity = [1x7 char]`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

```
% --- Executes on button press in addNotesButton.
function addNotesButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to addNotesButton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

contents = get(handles.artSevSel, 'String'); 
selectedSeverity = contents(get(handles.artSevSel, 'Value'))


return
```

Comment: You probably need to use {curly braces} to access the string, which is in a cell array. i.e. `contents{get(handles.artSevSel, 'Value')}`. Is that it?

Comment: @Benoit_11 well now it does work for some reason after physically re-typing the line...welp thanks!

Comment: haha yeah these things happen sometime :) Glad it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Benoit_11's suggestion. I wasn't reading the contents of the cell array. The last line should be surrounded by curly braces so that the function accesses the contents of the cell, not just the array.